# Looking for a javascript calendar that gives month view with the capability to block off dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I need an interactive calendar for my web application. I haven't worked with any calendar widgets before, so here I am hoping to pick you experts' brains.

Below are my requirements:

- the calendar is displayed in month view
- the capability to grey out certain dates to block them out from any events.

Optional but nice to have:

- users can easily add a new event to the calendar with a few simple mouse clicks on the calendar itself, avoiding the use of keyboard.

The calendar display that I have in mind is more like [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). The problem with FullCalendar is that I can't find a solution to block off dates.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

When initiating your calendar, pass a function (e.g. yourFunction) to the parameter select:

```
$('#yourdiv').fullCalendar(
    {...
     select: yourFunction,
     ...
    }, fcOtherSettings
);
```

`yourFunction` will be always triggered when a user attempts to create a new event. Then, within `yourFunction` you can validate whatever you want, e.g. prevent the user to create the event for certain dates.

In addition, you can overwrite the css of those dates (e.g. put a gray color, block cursor) to help users get a first hand impression of non-permitted dates.

Just as an example, all days before today with a gray background:

```
$('.fc-today').prevAll('td').css('background','gray');
$('.fc-today').parent().prevAll().find('td').css('background','gray');
```

Comment: You could also use `$('.fc-past').css('background','gray');` to color them gray

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI's calendar has the ability to lock out dates.

You need to use the "beforeShowDay" option and then run your lockout logic in there, I used it like such to only allow Mondays as selectable:

```
$('input[id$=txtCompareTo], input[id$=txtWeekOf]').datepicker({
      firstDay: 0,
      beforeShowDay: function (date) {
          return [date.getDay() == 0, "", ""];
      }
});
```

But, obviously, you can put whatever logic you need in the function to make it enable or disable days however you need.

Comment: I am looking for a calendar display not an input, so datepicker doesn't help in my case.

Comment: datepicker can display without an input.  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: But it does not display events on the calendar itself. The calendar display that I have in mind is more like [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). The problem with FullCalendar is that I can't find a solution to block off dates.

Comment: Ahh, I see, sorry I can't help you then.

Comment: No worries. You've helped me to clarified my question. Thanks, still.